# What is this part between the Su-35's jet exhaust nozzles?

Tags: aircraft-design, military, su-27

What is the long thing that sticks out between the Su-35's jet exhaust nozzles and what does it do?

[image]

Source: 4ever.eu

Comment: That's the stinger. The Su-35 will use it against an intruder if it's deemed a potential threat to the colony queen/aircraft carrier.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't an ovipositor?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The long thing has RWR (Radar warning Reciever) on its sides and has a [drogue parachute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drogue_parachute) in the middle. [This image](http://cdn.airplane-pictures.net/images/uploaded-images/2013/1/30/266113.jpg) shows the rear part open after deployment.

[image: Su 35 after chute deployment]

Image from [airplane-pictures.net](http://cdn.airplane-pictures.net/images/uploaded-images/2013/1/30/266113.jpg)

Incidentally, the aircraft serial number is 901, while the one in your image has a number 902.

Comment: Does the Radar warning Reciever do the same job that Hawker Siddeley Nimrod tails, with electronic warfare (ESM) sensors, do?

Comment: @Marine1 the Nimrods tail is a Magnetic Anomaly Detector, designed to detect a submerged submarine as the aircraft flies over it - its positioned in such a way because it has to be clear of the aircrafts magnetic field distortions.  The RWR on SU-35 and other aircraft merely detect when the aircraft is being hit by radar.

Answer (score 7):

If you are speaking of the grey volume, according to [this cutaway](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tPCp.jpg) by Alexey Mikheyev, it contains a Radar Warning Receiver/Electronic Intelligence System. Basically a system designed to detect if an hostile weapon system is locking/has locked on you.

Comment: You have copied the cutaway from its source to Stack Exchange's imgur.com server. It would be best to provide attribution of the source for the image in your answer. In addition, if the cutaway has a license that makes it reasonable to put on Stack Exchange's imgur.com server to share in your Answer, then the answer would be better if you display the image in your answer rather than just link to it.

Comment: @Makyen I agree, but none of this was available. The image was on pinterest with no attributable source except the one in the top left corner of the image (that I left untouched). If you have found any linkable source I will be happy to include it.

Comment: Then it would be better to have the link in your question be to the source, rather than a copy.  Moving a copy to Stack Exchange's imgur.com server introduces copyright issues to your question. Having, instead, a link to the page where you found the image leaves the copyright issues on that site.

Comment: @Makyen but in turn not copying to imgur introduces the problem that the link might go dead.

Comment: That is one of the risks of complying with copyright. You can mitigate this risk by finding an archive of the site, or having an archiving site create an archive.

Comment: @Mayken we've discussed in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/33274223#33274223). The outcome is that, as the author does not seem to have a website we can direct to, and his name is in the image, pointing to random 3rd party websites would not help him. I will report his name in the post.