# Why doesn't F-15 have a protruded cone at its rear like what the Su-35 has?

Tags: fighter, su-27, f-15

Why doesn't F-15 have a protruded cone-like structure at its rear like what the Su-35 has?

[image]

Left one is Su-35. Right one is F-15.

[This is Radar Warning Receiver.](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/32882/what-is-this-part-between-the-su-35s-jet-exhaust-nozzles)

Where is F-15's RWR?

Comment: Related: [What is this part between the Su-35's jet exhaust nozzles?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/32882/8730)

Comment: Because it doesn't need one.

Comment: Because the distance between the two engines are too large and need something there to fill the void to reduce drag. The side effect is it become a convenient host for rear facing electronics. Su-33 and Shenyang J15 have to shorten the beavertail because of higher attack of angle when landing and both have to endure the increased drag. F15 and others doesn't need it because the two engines are very close together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cause the rear radome of Su-35 has
1) Parachute,
2) A small radar , looking rear with range of 52 Km ,and
3) Unique Jammer against missiles , systems and radars.

F-15 is a fossil compared to the Su-35.
Not the same planes. Not the same role. Not comparable.

Comment: Su-27s also have that Radar Warning Receiver.

Answer (score 4):

As @RalphJ notes, it is not required. It is a design choice based on various considerations. The 'cone' in the Su-35 houses the RWR and the drogue chute. In case of F-15, however, the drogue chute is not used and the RWR antennae are located elsewhere (in the wing and vertical tail tips, to be exact).

The image below from a [BAE systems document](http://www.baesystems.com/en/download-en/20151124120655/1434554723415.pdf) shows the integration of [AN/ALR-56C Radar Warning Recievers](http://www.baesystems.com/en/product/an-alr-56-radar-warning-receivers) in the F-15 A/E aircraft.

[image: F-15 RWR]

Integration of AN/ALR-56C Radar Warning Receivers on F-15; image from [BAE systems](http://www.baesystems.com/en/download-en/20151124120655/1434554723415.pdf)