# What is the asymmetric feature on the rear of a Sukhoi Su-47?

Tags: feature-identification, experimental-aircraft, su-47

I saw this part on the rear of the Sukhoi Su-47 Berkut, and I can see that it is asymmetric. Is it maybe for interference, or is it a take-off aid because the Su-47 is a [STOL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STOL) plane?

What is it and why is it asymmetric?

[image: Su-47]

Edit:Second picture is mirrored

[image: Su-47]

Comment: It's just a thing put there to create asymmetry by someone who was a secret admirer of Burt Rutan.

Comment: Is it a reference to the ad-1?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> The Su-47 has two tailbooms of unequal length outboard of the exhaust nozzles. The shorter boom, on the left-hand side, houses rear-facing radar, while the longer boom houses a brake parachute.

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sukhoi_Su-47)

Related: [What is this part between the Su-35's jet exhaust nozzles?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/32882)

Note: Your second image is mirrored. Here's a real photo with the right (starboard) boom being the longer one:

> [image]
>   Su-47 (aka S-37) in lead, also notice the tail numbers of the formation (no mirroring); source: [wikimedia.org](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Sukhoi_Su-47_in_formation,_2005.jpg)

Comment: Interesting to note that even the *experimental* Su-47 has a [white nose radome](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/89180/15311)!

Comment: @Rodrigo: Assuming it's reasons 1 and/or 2 I mentioned in my answer, it still makes sense. Why change a manufacturing process and/or new standard just for an experimental.